# PHP beginner: How to "Order by" that query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

I have a rather (I think) easy problem to solve but being a PHP newbie, I can't seem to get the answer...

The query below, print a cloud of tags on my page. I'd like to add "ORDER BY TagID ASC" to this query so that the tags appeared according to their ID #, but I have no idea, where to put it (I didn't write that query, obviously).

```
<?php
   $tags = $data->select ( "Tag", "*" , NULL , 0 , 500 ) ;
   if ( ! empty ( $tags ) )
      foreach ( $tags as $tag ) :
         $counts = $data->count_record ( "Website_Tag" , array ( "TagID" => $tag["TagID"] ) ) ;

      if ( $counts > 20 )
         $font_size = $counts ;
      else
         $font_size = 11 ;

?>
<a style="font-size: <?php echo $font_size ?>px;" href="<?php echo base_url."coupons/".get_sef_url ( $tag["TagID"] , "Tag" ) ?>/"><?php echo $tag["TagName"] ?></a>

<?php
      endforeach ;
?>
```

Any help will be strongly appreciated? Thanks!

Comment: You're not using the built-in php mysql functions, so what are you using?

Comment: You need to specify which PHP framework or database abstraction layer you are using before anyone can reliably answer this question.

Comment: Pls don't use tabs when posting formatted code

Comment: Yes, there is a database abstraction layer I guess, one file starting with " class DataManipulator extends Database". Didn't realize that information was necessary, sorry!
And thanks for correcting the formating of the code. Lesson learned!

By the way, the answer below worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [sort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php)

```
<?php
   $tags = $data->select ( "Tag", "*" , NULL , 0 , 500 ) ;
   if ( ! empty ( $tags ) )
      sort($tags); // sort here
      foreach ( $tags as $tag ) :
         $counts = $data->count_record ( "Website_Tag" , array ( "TagID" => $tag["TagID"] ) ) ;

      if ( $counts > 20 )
         $font_size = $counts ;
      else
         $font_size = 11 ;

?>
<a style="font-size: <?php echo $font_size ?>px;" href="<?php echo base_url."coupons/".get_sef_url ( $tag["TagID"] , "Tag" ) ?>/"><?php echo $tag["TagName"] ?></a>

<?php
      endforeach ;
?>
```